# Jquery load select a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-load

So I am using Jquery's load function like so,

```
$('#id').load("http://www.thisiswhyimbroke.com");
```

I know you can add id selectors after the url, but the content im looking for is not contained within an id, is there a way I can select a particular class name?

Even further, if I could select the first li item, then select the class with name item within it, is that possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can provide any selector, for example

```
$('#id').load("http://www.thisiswhyimbroke.com li:first .someclass");
```

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/) :

> Loading Page Fragments
>
> The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of
>   the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special
>   syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are
>   included in the string, the portion of the string following the first
>   space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content
>   to be loaded.

Comment: ok wow that is actually very helpful now, thank you so much. I am assuming you can also grab specific tags within that correct?

Comment: You can go on with any selector.